# Effective way to pull a unique field value from Elasticsearch 2.4?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field called **memberInfoId** in Elasticsearch, whose value is unique in each document. I have thousands of documents in my Elasticsearch, so if I have to pull all the value of **memberInfoId**, **terms aggregation** seems to be very heavy. Any alternative to it?

Answer (score 0):

Since field value is unique, you can get memberinfoId of all documents

```
GET index/_search
{
  "_source": "memberinfoId" 
}
```

Result

```
 "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "9wm5jWsBsaS8x8rcaQum",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "memberinfoId" : 1
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "-Am5jWsBsaS8x8rcjwv5",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "memberinfoId" : 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

You can paginate above data using "from" and "size".

Comment: There are thousands of records and I don't think it's feasible to paginate over such large data. The better way could be using Scroll API but I am not sure if it's better than terms aggregation as we have to hit multiple times for Scroll API as well.

Comment: terms aggregation returns 10 record by default . Both in terms aggregation and fetching all documents you will have to  use from and size. Since you just need value I don;t think aggregation is needed. Scroll is also good option.